# Chinese Text commentary syntax highlighting

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting

Plain text inherited from [ctext.org](https://ctext.org) contain the following syntax: `{{...}}`

> 堯年十六，以唐侯升為天子，遂以為號。{{《論語·泰伯》疏
>
> 案曰：堯典正義云：徧檢書傳無帝堯卽位之年，則此似非伏生大傳文，疑出書緯。}}
>
> 辯章百姓。{{見《毛詩·采菽》正義、《史記·五帝紀》索隱、《後漢書》注}}
>
> 辨章百姓，百姓昭明。{{《癸辛雜識》前集引《尚書大傳》第一曰云云}}

Commentary within the braces are displayed [as such](https://ctext.org/wiki.pl?if=en&chapter=415472#%E5%B0%9A%E6%9B%B8%E5%A4%A7%E5%82%B3):

[image: display on ctext]

How can this be reproduced in `org-mode`? My guess is that I would need to work on faces and syntax tables.

---

Using @xuechunyang's answers below, I'd like to define another set of commentary markup on my own by changing some of the variables. Why doesn't this work?

```
(defface org-commentary-2
  '((t :foreground "blue2"))
  "Face for blue text in org mode")

(defun org-add-my-extra-markup ()
  (add-to-list 'org-font-lock-extra-keywords
               `(,(rx (group "((")
                      (group (+? anything))
                      (group "))"))
                 (1 '(face default invisible t))
                 (2 '(face org-commentary-2))
                 (3 '(face default invisible t)))))

(add-hook 'org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook #'org-add-my-extra-markup)
```

Comment: `}}` is missing in the first comment.

Comment: Yes - that's the way it is. I've not changed anything. If the behavior in line 1-2 is confusing (possibly a bug somewhere), I think we can just focus on lines 3-4 and get that to work for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt. I learnt `org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook` on https://www.gonsie.com/blorg/org-highlight.html. The `org-green` face is defined in @amitp's answer.

```el
(defun org-add-my-extra-markup ()
  (add-to-list 'org-font-lock-extra-keywords
               `(,(rx (group "{{")
                      (group (+? anything))
                      (group "}}"))
                 (1 '(face default invisible t))
                 (2 '(face org-green))
                 (3 '(face default invisible t)))))

(add-hook 'org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook #'org-add-my-extra-markup)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you want.

1. Apply a face (green text) to the area between `{{` and `}}`.
2. Hide the `{{` and `}}`.

For the first, you can define a green face and then use font-lock to mark the text:

```
(defface org-green
  '((t :foreground "green4"))
  "Face for green text in org mode")

(defun my/org-mode-font-lock ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '(("{{\\(.*\\)}}" 1 'org-green t))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my/org-mode-font-lock)
```

For the second, I am not sure. Font-lock normally applies faces, but `invisible` is a text property and not a face. An alternative is to use the org-hide face:

```
(defun my/org-mode-font-lock ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   '(("\\({{\\)\\(.*\\)\\(}}\\)"
      (1 'org-hide t)
      (2 'org-green t)
      (3 'org-hide t)
      ))))
```

Comment: I think the green text also needs to be slightly smaller than the usual text.

Comment: The size is controlled by `:height` so you can use `:height 0.9` after the `:foreground`, or do any other customizations to the face.